# Ошибка TypeError:'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, классы, атрибуты, декоратор

Пишу вот такой код на создание геометрических фигур. Хочу установить значние аrea при помощи декоратора @property. В итоге вышеописанная ошибка. Заранее благодарен за помощь

```
class GeometricFigure:

  def __init__(self, name, area, angles, perimeter):
    self.name = name
    self.__area = area
    self.angles = angles
    self.perimeter = perimeter
    print(f"Инициализирован экземпляр класса - '{self.name}' ")


  @property
  def p_area(self):
      print(f"Площадь фигуры '{self.name}' = {self.__area}")
      return self.__area

  @p_area.setter
  def p_area(self, value):
      print('Площадь фигуры установлена')
      if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
          raise ValueError('Значение не является числом')
      self.__area += 1
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Вы, видимо, неправильно используете свойство. Правильно делать так:

```
g = GeometricFigure('name', 20, 1, 2)
g.p_area = 1
print(g.p_area)
```

Вывод:

```
Инициализирован экземпляр класса - 'name' 
Площадь фигуры установлена
Площадь фигуры 'name' = 21
21
```

Ошибка будет, если вы попытаетесь использовать свойство как метод:

```
g.p_area(1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Свойство `g.p_area` возвращает целое число, а целое число нельзя использовать как функцию.

Comment: Большое спасибо, не обратил внимания на эту тонкость